# Is there a documentation for \setupTABLE?

Tags: tables, context, context-mkiv

I need to know which parameters can be passed to `\setupTABLE` command. Is there any documentation or can it be extracted from source ?

Comment: No. `\setupTABLE` is from package `TABLE` http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE

Comment: The wiki page gives the basic documentation (how to set options for a specific row, or a specific column, or a specific cell). It also describes options unique to TABLE (spanning rows and columns). All other options are inherited from `\framed`; so anything that works for `\framed` also works for `\setupTABLE`.

Answer (score 4):

You can find all valid keys for all available commands in [`setup-en.pdf`](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf).

[image]

The `inherits: \setupframed` means that all keys of `\setupframed` are also valid in `\setupTABLE`.